# How to add DataGridViewLinkColumn property to dynamically generated columns in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

**Developing In:** `c# winforms` without any Database Connections

**Description:** In my DataGridView, columns were dynamically generated.At some point some of the columns need to be DataGridViewLinkColumn property. I was tried in many ways but didn't achive this.

I hope someone from here would help me :)

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to switch off `AutoGenerateColumns`, then generate each column yourself.

Setup the normal columns as type `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`, then for the columns which need to be Linked columns set them up as type `DataGridViewLinkColumn`.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
       DataGridViewLinkColumn links = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();

        links.HeaderText = "Hello";
        links.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
        links.Text="http://microsoft.com";
        links.ActiveLinkColor = Color.White;
        links.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault;
        links.LinkColor = Color.Blue;
        links.TrackVisitedState = true;
        links.VisitedLinkColor = Color.YellowGreen;

        dataGridView.Columns.Add(links);
```